# Not getting a qr code for newly create Create React Native App

Tags: expo, create-react-native-app

I'm using Create-React-Native-App for the first time (I've used React before). I'm following instructions on a course on Coursera on how to setup and start a Create-React-Native-App application. The instructions are as follows:

---

At a convenient location on your computer, create a folder named ReactNative and move into that folder.

Then type the following at the prompt to create a new React Native application named confusion:

```
create-react-native-app confusion
```

This should create a new folder named confusion within your ReactNative folder and create the React Native application in that folder.

This will compile the project and then start serving the project at the address exp://<Your Computer's IP address>:19000.

Install the Expo client app on your iOS or Android phone and connect to the same wireless network as your computer.

On Android, use the Expo app to scan the QR code from your terminal to open your project. On iOS, follow on-screen instructions to get a link.

---

This is where I get stuck. when I use "npm start" I get "Welcome to React Native! Learn once, write anywhere" but no QR code in sight. As far as I know I'm using the latest version of Create-React-Native-App. I have the Expo client app on my Android and I'm also on the same wireless network as my computer.